# How can i use jquery validation plugin in my project

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery validation plugin to validate time in jquery ...but it is always showing an error which is really making me to pull my hair.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addMethod' of undefined

```
 $("input").blur(function() {
                //var check =$(this).closest('tr').find('input');
                $(this).each(function() {
                $.validator.addMethod(this, function(value, element) {  
                return this.optional(element) || /^(([0-1]?[0-9])|([2][0-3])):([0-5]?[0-9])(:([0-5]?[0-9]))?$/i.test(value);  
                    }, "Please enter a valid time.");

              $("#check").validate({
                          rules: {
                             input: "required time"
                                  }

                });
```

Comment: here #check is my form id..

Comment: First, try the validator without the extended method. Just with a basic "required" for instance. If this works, try to init the validator before add the method.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the [validator library](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) in your page, include the [library](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js) in your page

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

And

```
$.validator.addMethod('timevalue', function(value, element) {  
    return this.optional(element) || /^(([0-1]?[0-9])|([2][0-3])):([0-5]?[0-9])(:([0-5]?[0-9]))?$/i.test(value);  
}, "Please enter a valid time.");


$("#check").validate({
    rules: {
        timevalue: true
    }
});
```

Comment: i have passed validator library though ot showing the same error.. @Arun P Johny